# Javascript Variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, class, variables, events, undefined

why does it always say `undefined` when I move the mouse? It should return true, right? I hope somebody can help me :)
Before you ask I called the class in another JavaScript file!

```
class Block {

 constructor() {

    this.movable = true;
    this.move = false;

    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.classList.add("block");

    this.div.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {

        console.log(this.movable); 

    });
    this.div.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {

        this.move = true;
        console.log("test");

    });
    this.div.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {

        this.move = false;
        console.log("test1");

    });

 }
 add() {

     document.body.appendChild(this.div);

 }
 remove() {

     document.body.removeChild(this.div);

 }

}
```

Comment: What, exactly, is undefined? Post the actual error, not the paraphrased error, if you could

Comment: Who says undefined? Which IDE?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @PaulHanneforth! You've run into a very common problem that most Javascript developers run into every now and then. Many articles have been written on the topic - I've tried to give the practical perspective and show three common ways to solve it in my answer below. If anything is unclear, let me know in the comments and I will try to make it clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **ES6** arrow function `()=>{}` to solve your problem. The arrow function uses `this` of the current context of execution. In this case it is the instance of the `class` having the initialized `movable` property.

Where a normal anonymous function will use the `this` of the object on which the listener is attached to, in your case that is the `div`. As the `div` has no `movable` property you are getting `undefined`.

```js
class Test{

 constructor() {
      this.movable = true;
      this.move = false;

      this.div = document.createElement("div");
    
      this.div.classList.add("block");

      this.div.addEventListener("mousemove", ()=> {
          console.log(this.movable); 
      });
      this.div.addEventListener("mousedown", ()=> {
          this.move = true;
          console.log("test");
      });
      this.div.addEventListener("mouseup", ()=> {
          this.move = false;
          console.log("test1");
      });
    }

 add(){
     this.div.textContent ="Hover over me.";
     document.body.appendChild(this.div);
 }

 remove(){
     document.body.removeChild(this.div);
 }

}
var test = new Test();
test.add();
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Quoting from MDN:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You have to study about javascript context.

every each function has own `this`. so if you apply external `this`, you should bind this.

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#bind_method

```
class Block {
    constructor() {
        this.movable = true;
        this.move = false;

        this.div = document.createElement("div");
        this.div.classList.add("block");

        this.div.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
            console.log(this.movable); 
        }.bind(this)); // bind this!!
        this.div.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
            this.move = true;
            console.log("test");
        }.bind(this)); // bind this!!
        this.div.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
            this.move = false;
            console.log("test1");
        }.bind(this)); // bind this!!

    }
    add() {
        document.body.appendChild(this.div);
    }
    remove() {
        document.body.removeChild(this.div);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's due to `this` scoping.

It turns out `this` from your constructor is not the same as the one from your callback:

```
class Block {
    constructor() {
        // here this is your instance of your class block
        this.movable = true;


        this.div.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
            // here it's not since each function get's it's own from how it's called
            // since it is called by `div.addEventListener` and not you directly
            // JS had no way to get the root this
            console.log(this.movable); 

        });
    }
}
```

The simplest solution is to use **ES6** arrow functions.

```
class Block {
    constructor() {
        // here this is your instance of your class block
        this.movable = true;


        this.div.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
            // this is bound to your instance of class block in this scope too !
            console.log(this.movable); 
        });
    }
}
```

Note the `() => {` instead of `function () {` !

This works because arrow function don't have theyre own this but instead keep the one they had access to where they were created, very handy.

Answer (score 1):

As the others mentioned, the reason you are getting `undefined` is `this` inside your event handler functions is **not** the instance of the class (as you're expecting).

You have **three ways to fix that**, two of them based off ES5, one of them based off ES6 (which shouldn't be a problem - you're using ES6 already in your code).

### 1 Explicitly bind the outer `this` to your handler functions using `Function.prototype.bind()`.

`bind()` tells a functions what to use as `this` inside of its function body.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.movable = true;
    this.move = false;
    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.classList.add("block");
    this.div.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
      console.log(this.movable);
    }.bind(this)); // .bind(this)
    this.div.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
      this.move = true;
      console.log("test");
    }.bind(this)); // .bind(this)
    this.div.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
      this.move = false;
      console.log("test1");
    }.bind(this)); // .bind(this)
  }
  add() {
    this.div.textContent = "Test";
    document.body.appendChild(this.div);
  }
  remove() {
    document.body.removeChild(this.div);
  }
}
var test = new Test();
test.add();
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

### 2 Store the reference to the class instance in a variable (here: `self`) and use that inside the handler function.

This used to be a very common pattern to solve the problem you've crashed into as well. With everyone jumping onto the ES6-train nowadays it's becoming less and less used. I do like it also for improved readability.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    const self = this; // reference to this stored in self
    this.movable = true;
    this.move = false;
    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.classList.add("block");
    this.div.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
      console.log(self.movable); // self instead of this used
    });
    this.div.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
      self.move = true; // self instead of this used
      console.log("test");
    });
    this.div.addEventListener("mouseup", fucntion() {
      self.move = false; // self instead of this used
      console.log("test1");
    });
  }
  add() {
    this.div.textContent = "Test";
    document.body.appendChild(this.div);
  }
  remove() {
    document.body.removeChild(this.div);
  }
}
var test = new Test();
test.add();
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

### 3 Use ES6 arrow function syntax.

Arrow functions don't have their own `this` (which can be a downside in some cases!), which makes the "outer" `this` available to them.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.movable = true;
    this.move = false;
    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.classList.add("block");
    this.div.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
      console.log(this.movable);
    });
    this.div.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
      this.move = true;
      console.log("test");
    });
    this.div.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      this.move = false;
      console.log("test1");
    });
  }
  add() {
    this.div.textContent = "Test";
    document.body.appendChild(this.div);
  }
  remove() {
    document.body.removeChild(this.div);
  }
}
var test = new Test();
test.add();
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

As others mentioned, if not using arrow functions for defining event handlers, `this` inside the handler willl usually hold a reference to the element the event was raised on (which is often very useful). To still access that despite using arrow functions, you can use the `event.target` property:

```
// notice I name a parameter e here
// which will hold the event object
// that is always passed to the event
// handler automatically - it just needs 
// a name to make it accessible inside
(e) => { console.log(e.target); }
```